# Add Image or style to each tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

i have app with many tabs, i want to add image or style to each tab , how please?

```
th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost_template_two_tabs);
th.setup();
// all tab
spec = th.newTabSpec("All");
spec.setIndicator("All");
spec.setContent(R.id.tab_template_two_tabs_all);
th.addTab(spec);
// favorite tab
spec = th.newTabSpec("Favorite");
spec.setIndicator("Favorite");
spec.setContent(R.id.tab_template_two_tabs_favorite);
th.addTab(spec);
th.setCurrentTab(1);
```

Thanks

Comment: why they just put there code and leave ? please someone help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :
Call this from your OnCreate() method:

```
 setTabs();
```

Then put this code

```
 private void setTabs()
{
    addTab(R.drawable.ic_icon1, Activity.class, "All");
    addTab(R.drawable.ic_icon2, Activity1.class, "Favorite");
}

private void addTab(int drawableId, Class<?> c, String labelId)
{
    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab"+ labelId);  

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);
    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}
```

Then Create tab_indicator.xml in drawable folder and put this code.There you can set different colours when it is pressed,focused etc...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press" />
  </selector>
```

In layouts create tab_indicator.xml and put this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="55dip"    
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"

/> 

<TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
/>    
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will read it and apply it , then tell you what is the results

Comment: in your code `R.layout.tab_indicator` have to be `R.drawable.tab_indicator` right? and what is `getTabWidget()` and `R.id.title`and `R.id.icon`

Comment: thansk for your replay, i will check

Comment: in your code instread on `@drawable/tab_unselected` and `@drawable/tab_selected` and `@drawable/tab_focus`i have to put my images right ?

Comment: there is no method `getTabWidget()`

Comment: and what isfor `getTabWidget` there is no method like it

Comment: import this                                                    import android.app.TabActivity;

Comment: i imported it, and still the method no exist

Comment: `import android.app.TabActivity;` this is it, i reaaly import it ,and +1 4 u

Comment: maybe i should say `tabHost.gettabwidget`

Comment: i din't used that may be you can try with that.

Comment: it didn't work ,an exception is thrown, i accept your answer, thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image to the tab as below :

> ```
> tabHost.newTabSpec("All").setIndicator(null,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(R.id.tab_template_two_tabs_all);
> ```

Or to set the style try this:

> ```
>  tabHost.newTabSpec("All").setIndicator(null,res.getDrawable(R.style.myStyle)).setContent(R.id.tab_template_two_tabs_all);
> ```

Comment: replace with getResources if on fragment or activity. It provides access to resources if used like Resources res = getResources();