# How to custom tabs with fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I just want to customize the tabs on my app to a picturs with selector or something where i need to begin? here is my code.
now my app is with the regular black and blue tabs but i want to make it custom

what should i do?
    here is my code:

**Class a**

```
  public class ListFragment extends Fragment{

        basAdapterCustom adapter;
        ListView lv;
        ArrayList<Clock> list;
        private DbHandler hand;
        Context context;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
            context = getActivity();

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");

            hand = new DbHandler(context);
            list = new ArrayList<Clock>();

            lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listOfShifts);
            adapter = new basAdapterCustom(list, getActivity());
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            refreshList();
            return v;
        }



        //like on "resume":
        @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
            // Make sure that we are currently visible
            if (this.isVisible()) {
                refreshList();
                if (!isVisibleToUser) {
                    // TODO stop
                }
            }
        }



        private void refreshList() {

            list = hand.getByWorkName();
            adapter = new basAdapterCustom(list,getActivity());

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

**class b:**

```
public class ClockFragment extends Fragment{


    DbHandler hand;


    Context context;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clock, container,false);

        context = getActivity();

        hand = new DbHandler(context);

        return v;
    }


    // ADD to .Db
    public void addToDb(View v){
        hand.add(new Clock(0, dateDay));    

    }


}
```

**class mainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, OnPageChangeListener{

    public static final String TAG = "myClock";

    String[] tabMenu = {"FRAG A","FRAG B","FRAG C"};

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "OnCreate = MainActivity (Pager");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager );
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (String tabsNames : tabMenu) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabsNames).setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    }

    //  public void transDialog(){
    //      Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    //  }





    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }




    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {        
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);      
    }

}
```

**PagetAdapter.class**

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "myClock";


    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        Log.d(TAG, " CLASS : TabPagerAdapter");
        switch (index) {
        case 0:

            return new ListFragment();
        case 1:
            return new ClockFragment();
        case 2:
            return new SettingFragment();

        default:
            break;
        }       
        Log.d(TAG, " CLASS : TabPagerAdapter = "+index);
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried this? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs

Comment: i dont want to change the all theme . just to customize the tabs with my own pictures i made..

Comment: Have a look at: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176867/use-different-color-for-different-actionbar-tab/18253739#18253739)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String tabsNames : tabMenu) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabsNames).setTabListener(this));
}
```

Change this to:

```
for (String tabsNames : tabMenu) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabsNames).setTabListener(this).setIcon(resources.getDrawable(<drawable_id>));
}
```

Maybe, you should first create an array with drawable id's, then in 'for' loop take id with something like `.setIcon(resources.getDrawable(icons[i])`

If you have already put the drawables for icons into corresponding folders, you can give me their names and I'll show you the full code.

Comment: Thanks but what about if i want to change the background color of the tabs or change the selector states?

Comment: Try to look through this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535085/add-image-or-style-to-each-tab

Comment: i look it that before but i cant undwrstand the "tabHost" im a little bit new with "tabs" .. you can guide me how can i add this to my existing code?

Comment: There's a comment with link to your question - by @user2145222. It's quite good.

If you asking me "what about if i want to do something" - I'm a bit confused and willing to answer "you need to know android framework and use it".

I can't give you an answer for all possible "what if"'s. Give some details like what colours and icons you are willing to add and I'll try to help and post working code, and you'll see and understand the idea and will be able to continue by your own.